# Adding a number to a search to display correct result in php/laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have created a simple search function that works by searching my required fields to match my keywords. This works fine for every column apart from my "Id" column, because when I display my ID in the table I actually add + 500 and some text. This is basically because the ID column is my booking/order reference and I didn't want to start at 0 and felt it easier to just offset the displayed result.

Basically I need it to add 500 to the search if when checking against the request_id column. So for the first record in the table would be 1 + 500 + my prefix which displays as SP-501. It I search for 501, it actually brings up record 501 in the table and not the correct one.

Heres my code:

```
public function search()
{

    $search = \Request::get('search'); 

    $bookings = LcsBooking::where('request_email','like','%'.$search.'%')
        ->orWhere('request_id', 'like', '%'.$search.'%')
        ->orWhere('request_name', 'like', '%'.$search.'%')
        ->orWhere('request_arrival', 'like', '%'.$search.'%')
        ->orWhere('request_return', 'like', '%'.$search.'%')
        ->orWhere('request_txauthno', 'like', '%'.$search.'%')
        ->orWhere('request_vehicle_reg', 'like', '%'.$search.'%')
        ->orWhere('request_mobile', 'like', '%'.$search.'%')
        ->orderBy('request_id', 'DESC')
        ->paginate(20);

    return view('admin.lcs.search',compact('bookings'));
}
```

Comment: So you're saying your ID field has characters like SP-501? Stored in the database? If so, this is very bad practice. And would make your `int ID` column a string, not an integer, Never modify auto incrementing IDs. Instead, if you MUST transform the ID to some sort of reference number, create a separate column OR what I would do is use a library like https://github.com/vinkla/hashids to mask the ID when you display it in the view. You don't ever want anyone to se your vanilla ID numbers. You can set attribute in view to transform this automatically.

Comment: No, the id is auto increment as normal. I create a booking_id by adding a prefix when displaying in a table and then adding 500 to the id

Comment: Not sure I fully understand, can't you just do `->orWhere('request_id', 'like', '%'.$search.' 500%')`

Comment: It's my fault, I'm rubbish at explaining. Basically my search is searching the database using my search string, but that doesn't work if I want to match my request_id because what I display in my view is a reference number generated by taking the id and adding 500 to id, so record with id of 100 is actually displayed as 600 in my table because I'm adding 500 to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just make a check before to see if it's a string integer, and if so, add 500 to it.

```
$search = \Request::get('search'); 
$id = ctype_digit($search) ? $search + 500 : $search;

$bookings = LcsBooking::where('request_email','like','%'.$search.'%')
    ->orWhere('request_id', 'like', '%'.$id.'%')
    ->orWhere('request_name', 'like', '%'.$search.'%')
    // and so on...
```

Comment: That did it, Thanks a lot Joel. Much appreciated :)